# password input starts JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jqwidget

I created a password input like this:

```
<form class="form" id="form" target="form-iframe" method="post" action="/php/password.php">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        
    </form>
    
    <iframe id="form-iframe" name="form-iframe" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

/php/password.php looks like this

```
<?php
$formData = array(
    "password" => $_POST["password"]
);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM data");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$password = $fetch ["password"]."";


$imagepath= "../jpg/P5010905.jpeg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
        

if($formData['password'] == $password ) {

    $pic =  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
            imagejpeg($image);
    
}

echo $pic;
?>
```

this works just fine.

On my site, there's also a slider object from jqwidgets, which is disabled by default. To enable it, I need in JavaScript

```
$('#light1').jqxSlider({ disabled: false });
```

How can I enable the slider after the authentication?

Comment: This looks promising for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/pfF53/

Answer (score 0):

you can use java script inside php either inside echo or closing ht e php tag and start  tag.

for example

```
If(Authentication==true){

 echo "<script>$('#light1').jqxSlider({ disabled: false });</script>"
}

else
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me. Maybe I need to link 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxslider.js"></script>
in the /php/password.php file?

Comment: tell me if the slider in passowrd.php file ? or you are redirecting it to some other page from password.php after authentication and that page has got the slider?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that?

```
function submitLogin(enteredUsername, enteredPassword) {

      $.post('login.php', {username: enteredUsername, password:enteredPassword},   
      function(response) {
          if (response.result == true) {
             $('#light1').jqxSlider({ disabled: false });
          } else {
             // fail code here
          }
      }, 'json');
    }
```